# How to install mysql 5.1 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, opentaps

I have **opentaps** application that uses **mysql 5.1 version**.
I installed opentaps on **ubuntu** and I want to **install mysql 5.1 version**.

How to install mysql 5.1 on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: MySQL 5.1 was end-of-lifed in 2013. While you might be able to find a package from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/, it's highly inadvisable.

Comment: @ceejayoz Maybe the OP is downloading to test something related to the upgrade process in a VM. That's currently my situation where I'm trying to upgrade 5.1 to at least 5.7, but want to make sure it works fine using a `.dump` of the database on a VM before making the changes on a production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/
- In the dropdown box, choose MySQL 5.1.73 from Nov 8, 2013.
- Click Download for Linux - Generic (glibc 2.3) (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive
- cd to the downloads directory (I'll assume it's Downloads)

```
tar -zxf mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz
cd mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23
```

bin/mysqld with whatever options you prefer.

e.g.

```
export MYSQLDIR=Downloads/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23
scripts/mysql_install_db
sudo bin/mysqld --no-defaults --basedir=$HOME/$MYSQLDIR --datadir=$HOME/$MYSQLDIR/data --lower-case-table-names=1 --user=root
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  How about starting from service.

Comment: I start mysql but I can not stop it. Can you help with creating a service and connecting to mysql?

Comment: ```cd to the directory where you downloaded.
To stop the server:
bin/mysqladmin --user=root shutdown
To start the client locally:
(I assume you alread said sudo apt-get install libncursesw5)
bin/mysql --user=root --host=127.0.0.1
To start mysqld when starting Ubuntu:
I won't help with that.
```